# Is differential number density the same as flux density?

Tags: cosmology, photons, astrophysics, astronomy

I'm trying to convert the differential number density of photons to luminosity (using slide 17 of `https://www.astro.rug.nl/~sctrager/teaching/OA/Photons.pdf`) and here they find luminosity using photon flux density. I was wondering if this is the same as differential photon number density, and if not how can I find luminosity using differential photon number density?